# Mongoexport Date Format

Tags: excel, mongodb

I have a Mongo DB Collection:

```
db.LoginCount.find().pretty()

{
    "_id": "test",
    "value": 1,
    "yesterday": "2013-5-1"
```

When I did a MongoDBExport, this way:

```
mongoexport --host localhost --db test --collection "LoginCount" --csv --out sai.csv --fields _id,value,yesterday
```

I got the `Yesterday` field output formatted `5/1/2013`:

[image: SO16331375 question example]

but I need the output in this format: `2013-5-1`.

Please tell me how it's possible?

Comment: Isn't Excel correctly interpreting 2013-5-1 as a date and just showing it to you in the month-day-year format rather than the sensible yyyy-mm-dd format?

Comment: May be , but i want in YYYY-MM-DD format only

Comment: Then you have an Excel problem, not a MongoDB problem.

Comment: How can this be a Excel problem ?? so is this possible to notify excel not to interpet data during MongoExport ??

Comment: Once you have imported data into Excel, it determines the date format: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/format-a-date-the-way-you-want-HA102809474.aspx

Comment: Yes, excel knows that it is a date and shows it in the format that you specify in the control panel of windows